# Is there a recommended cryptoperiod for HMAC hashing keys?

Tags: hmac

I have an application that receives certain pseudo-random input values and computes their keyed hash using HMAC-SHA256. The hashing key itself is 256-bits long, generated at random by a CSRNG.

Two questions:

1. Which category does the hashing key fall under in NIST's 2016 Recommendations? Is it a "Symmetric Data Encryption Key"?
2. If it doesn't fall under any of those categories, is there a recommended cryptoperiod for it, or can I use it *ad eternum*?

(I suspect that this is an irrelevant detail, but the pseudo-random input values the application is processing are themselves HMACs of other input values. However, they are computed by a third party. So, since I do not know or have access to the hashing key they use, I'm treating them as "pseudo-random.")

Comment: Cryptographically it should be good forever. Changing keys might still be useful to limit the impact of a compromised key.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically as pointed out by @CodesInChaos there is no need to rotate keys as long as they remain secret.

Also as @CodesInChaos points out, you need to architect the system for key rotation in the event of key compromise.

The best way to do that is to build key rotation *into the app and operational tooling*, and then put procedures in place to rotate keys regularly. That way you know key rotation will actually work when you *really* need it.

During the Heartbleed incident there were *banks* that were unable to re-key many of their certificates for several *months* despite regulator requirements that they be changed immediately. Rekeying was an infrequent manual process on their varied and ancient systems; some had never been re-keyed and nobody in house knew how to do it. It simply couldn't be done in a timely manner.

Regular exercise of key rotation prevents this sort of problem. Automation makes it easy. Think of it as DR planning and testing for your crypto keys.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, thanks. Just one final question: would you say that an HMAC key should be considered a symmetric authentication key or a symmetric encryption key (or neither) under NIST SP800-57 Part 1?

Comment: @GSantos HMAC = Hashed Message _Authentication_ Code.